# Flutter - using retrofit with injectable

Tags: flutter, retrofit, injectable

I am trying to use retrofit along with injectable

I am following clean architecture, and in the repo class i want to inject the retrofit client but i cant annotate the client with injectable since its abstract and i cant annotate the implementation because it is generated

I tried to annotate the generated file but that wont work because it will remove my changes the next time build runner is called

is there a proper way to solve this problem

i wont post my code because there isnt much to it

Comment: Implement the abstract class?

Comment: the implementation of the abstract class is generated automatically , i can't modify it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you use the `@module` annotation and create a "*RetrofitInjectableModule*". As such:

```
@module  
abstract class RetrofitInjectableModule {  
   BackendService getService(ApiClient client, @factoryParam String url) => BackendService(client, url);  
}
```

Where `BackendService` is your `RestClient`.

Read about `@module` on https://pub.dev/packages/injectable